# Can we use sqoop through cassandra java driver?

Tags: postgresql, import, cassandra, sqoop, datastax

I want to transfer data from postgresql to cassandra database.As per my knowledge we can use sqoop with datastax enterprise 2.0. But i am using cassandra java driver.How can i achieve this, Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Datastax Enterprise you will already have a sqoop installation under the DSE/Resources folder. You will have to configure the DSE environment for Hadoop use and make sure you start dse/cassandra in Analytics mode. You then use the dse sqoop commands.

You can find more details [HERE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsDseCmds.html)

If you're not running DSE you will have to install Hadoop/Sqoop and get it configured. Sqoop will work with Hadoop Map/Reduce to process your data into Cassandra. Once you have Sqoop running you will use an Options file to detail the connection and parameters for import. Its a little more work to run this all standalone unless you have set up Hadoop before.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using Datastax Enterprise.